# Create table in mariadb database with loop code php and write on

Tags: php, mariadb

When the amount field in the database reached a certain value, I wrote an order to create another table, it does, but it no longer writes in the new table and still writes in the previous table. And I want this to mean making the create table run several times in the loop, which it can't, can anyone help me

Comment: It is generally 'wrong' to have multiple tables for one set of data.  Please elaborate on why you are doing such.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It is quite feasible to have a billion rows in a table.

Comment: I agree with the above remark: "It is generally 'wrong' to have multiple tables for one set of data.". Could you please detail your question with the schema of your table and your SQL query for insert?

Comment: I want to collect the money to buy 1,000 houses and the amount of each house is, for example, 100,000,000. I want to show the money of each house that is being accumulated, this with a chart and it reached 100,000,000, the next house is registered in another table.

Comment: Edit you question to include a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) of this. Table structure, sample data, expected output are needed.